# iPad Redirect based on orientation

Tags: html, ipad, redirect, orientation

I NEED AN HTML REDIRECT based upon what orientation of the iPad when loaded.

So I have made two websites. One REGULAR:for iPad-horizontal/PC/macbook and another IPHONE :for iphone-horizontal/iphone-vertical/ipad-vertical

I want to redirect based on device- which is regular BUT a very specific need is that I want an iPad to redirect to the min site only when it is horizontal and it should go to the IPHONE site if it is loaded while vertical.
I do not need the site to change necessarily when the iPad is rotated.

Sorry if this information was hidden in another question but I could not find the exact answer that I need.

Thanks so much for any replies

Answer (score 0):

You could try listening to `deviceorientation` event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by screen size rather than device, targeting each specific device via screen resolutions.

JavaScript:

```
var
Responsive = {

maxPhoneWidth: 775,

maxTabletWidth: 925,


//REDIRECT BASED ON CONFIGURABLE MAX WIDTH THRESHOLD

maxWidthRedirect: 
function
(maxWidth, url) {

var
viewport = 
this
.getWindowSize();



//ADD EXCLUSION IN HASH IN CASE DESKTOP VIEWING IS INTENDED

if
(window.location.hash != 
'#desktop'
&& viewport.width < maxWidth)

window.location.href = url;

},



//REDIRECT BASED ON RECOMMENDED PHONE WIDTH THRESHOLD

mobileRedirect: 
function
(url) {

this
.maxWidthRedirect(this
.
maxPhoneWidth, url);

},



//REDIRECT BASED ON RECOMMENDED TABLET WIDTH THRESHOLD

tabletRedirect: 
function
(url) {

this
.maxWidthRedirect(this.maxTabletWidth, url);

},



//DETERMINE CROSS-BROWSER SCREEN SIZE

getWindowSize: 
function
() {

var
w = window,

d = document,

e = d.documentElement,

g = d.getElementsByTagName(
'body'
)[0],

x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,

y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;


return
{ width: x, height: y };

}
};
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<!-- REDIRECT USERS TO MOBILE SITE IF LESS THAN 775PX -->    
<script src="/Scripts/Responsive.js"></script>

<script>Responsive.maxWidthRedirect(775, 'http://example.com');</script>

</head>

<body>
//your code goes here
</body>

</html>
```

Refer to: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2014AprJun/1212.html

Comment: thanks so much. in my test the ipad and my imac both slip past teh test, but i assume i have to fiddle with the numbers in the javascript file until the ipad goes a separate way. cheers

Comment: No problem! If my answer was helpful be sure to check it as an accepted answer for future users to use it in a time of need.